# Whats a/the "bluebook" in the context of network programming?

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, ipv6, ethernet

My local header `/usr/include/linux/if_ether.h` has the following define:

```
#define ETH_P_IPV6     0x86DD /* IPv6 over bluebook */
```

What is bluebook? I've never heard this term, and a cursory internet search didn't reveal anything related to network programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the archives of the internet:

> In 1979, Digital Equipment Corporation (DEC), Intel, and Xerox came
>   together for the purpose of standardizing an Ethernet system that any
>   company could use. In September 1980 the three companies released
>   Version 1.0 of the first Ethernet specification called the “Ethernet
>   Blue Book”, or “DIX standard” (after the initials of the three
>   companies). It defined the “thick” Ethernet system (10Base5), based on
>   a 10 Mb/s CSMA/CD (CarrierSense Multiple Access with Collision
>   Detection) protocol. It is known as “thick” Ethernet because of the
>   thick coaxial cable used to connect devices on the network. The first
>   Ethernet controller boards based on the DIX standard became available
>   about 1982.

Quote from [here](https://antrix.net/static/pages/about/dsarda_btech.pdf). So all-in-all it's just a fancy nickname of Ethernet.

Comment: I wonder why the author felt the need to clarify "over ethernet" when defining a constant used in the ethernet protocol, with a name beginning with `ETH`, in a file called `if_ether.h` :)